# Can anyone there advise me where to find GPS algorithm platform

Tags: gps

I'm looking for GPS enabling platform to speed up my wireless app implementation.

I will really be happy to find some short cut, like supported libraries etc

Comment: Do you just need to be able to get latitude/longitude/altitude etc from your device? What OS? Do you need something that will automatically fall back to cell tower triangulation?

Answer (score 0):

You may find [www.location-engine.com](http://www.location-engine.com) helpful. This is a web service that I have developed that lets you store location based entities and query them by geographical region. It can save you the trouble of having to implement and maintain a geographical database server.